# Configuring nginx to server assets files in angular

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I'm getting data from `assets` folder. On my local machine, I'm able to get the data with this url:

`http://localhost:4200/assets/data.json`

But when I deploy my app using docker in a `VM`, I'm getting an `HTTP 404` error.

The HTTP request:

```
http://192.168.xxx.xxx:22/assets/data.json
```

Error:

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.17.7</center>
</body>
```

Here's my docker file

```
FROM node:alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=builder /app/dist/proj/* /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

I figured out that I should also add an nginx config file  like in [this example](https://marcofranssen.nl/run-your-angular-app-in-a-nginx-docker-container/)

I would like how to configue in my case nginx to serve asset files

Comment: Is it there?  You can `docker run --rm yourimage ls /usr/share/index/html` to take a look at the built container filesystem.

Comment: Actually there is no config file. The app runs but not the when I request via Http requests a static files

Answer (score 5):

I have found the solution.

My issue is that I was the `*` in `/app/dist/proj/*` , the command copy all files in the same directory level  in my case in `html` instead of keeping files in a subdirectory `assets`

I removed `*`and that worked fine

Answer (score 0):

This configuration is working for me:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:alpine AS build-stage

WORKDIR /app

# to use cache on node_modules
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install

COPY . /app/
RUN npm run build --prod

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html/

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**nginx.conf**

```
events {}

http{
    server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
    }
}
```